# Using fgets after scanf

Tags: c, function, scanf, fgets

I want to get rid of buffer overflow and I am using `fgets` instead of `scanf` to limit the characters. But whenever I enter something with `scanf` before `fgets`, it doesn't work correctly anymore.

**This code works correctly**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 char name[10];
 printf("Who are you? \n");

 fgets(name,10,stdin);                   

 printf("Good to meet you, %s.\n",name);
 return(0);
}
```

**This code does not read *name* correctly**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15

int new_acc();
int view_list();
int main(){    
    int one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4, five=5, six=6, seven=7, choice;
    int new_account, list;

    printf("%d. Create new account\n",one);

    printf("Enter you choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if (choice==one){new_account = new_acc();}
    return 0;
}

int new_acc(){
    char name[MAX], address, account;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, MAX, stdin);          /* it is the code */
}
```

Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Consume `\n` before calling `fgets()`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [scanf leaves new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer/5240807?r=SearchResults#5240807)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix `scanf()` with `fgets()` in the same code.

`scanf("%d",&choice);` does not consume all the *line* - it leaves the trailing `'\n'` for the later `fgets()` to consume as an empty line.

`scanf()` is difficult to use in a secure fashion.

Comment: Then how to write fgets instead of scanf?

Comment: `char buffer[80]; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); choice = atoi(buffer);` is a simple alternative.  It omits various error checks, but something to get you going.

Comment: I am not getting.